# Company has wrong tax code

Tags: united-kingdom

The company I recently started working for had my wrong National Insurance number (off by a digit). I contacted them to get it rectified but it seemingly wasn't rectified in time for my first pay cheque. I've emailed them to ensure it gets rectified for my next pay cheque but my current pay was taxed at the 0T tax rate.

What's the process for getting my tax back? Do I ring HMRC and tell them the NI number it was taxed too and the correct one? Will it get fixed when work rectify it?

Comment: I seem to have made an assumption, but a clarification from you would be useful: Is this a new employer which has got your NI number wrong in your first month working there, or have you been working with the same employer (with the same incorrect tax code) since before April?

Comment: Yep, a new employer and I've just received my first pay cheque.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I've suggested an edit to your question to incorporate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be dealt with via PAYE (pay-as-you-earn) taxation. Every month, when your employer runs the payroll, they calculate (based on your current tax code) what your total tax-to-date should be, subtract the tax you've paid up to the end of the previous month, and hence calculate the tax you should pay this month.

The tax year runs from April to March. Given today's date, I am not sure whether your company got it wrong for July or August, but this is immaterial. Either way the next month (August or September respectively) is still in the same tax year, so they can resolve it. For anyone else this question may apply to in the future: if they messed up the March payslip then your company cannot rectify it through PAYE; you would have to contact HMRC and explain the situation. They will tell you what forms you need to fill out / what information to provide them.